# How to implement JXTA for wireless connectivity?

Tags: java, android, device, connectivity, jxta

Is it possible,
if two devices that are turning on their Wifi. But they're not connected
to any network. And then.... they want to implement JXTA (peer2peer) 
activities on android. How?

What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: **[peerdroid](https://code.google.com/p/peerdroid/)**.

Peer Droid is the porting of JXME protocol to Android Platform. It allows the Android Developers to create application for Android platform that uses the features of JXTA system along with Android potential, interacting with other mobile terminals and other traditional peers (Personal-Computer).

You can go to ***source*** -> ***browse*** -> ***trunk*** -> ***PeerDroidSample*** and see some piece of code.

Tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/peerdroid/wiki/PeerDroidTutorial

[]'s

Comment: That's true. But unfortunately, this PeerDroid need the RDV to list down all the IP address for making the Peer know (to communicate) the data. Which means that's not true direct communication what I asked,... @FelipeVasconcelos. 
Let's assume you have two devices turning on The WIfi. But they want to communicate without any intermediary. I saw JXTA is not the way out. CMIIW.